# How does 受 work in this context (on the first article)?

Tags: grammar

I just read the following sentence on 人名网 mobile:

> 三文鱼寿司是**很受**中国人欢迎的寿司种类，甚至有不少中国人到日本的回转寿司店也只点三文鱼。

But [on web version](http://world.people.com.cn/n1/2017/0914/c1002-29535768.html), the expression is the following:

> 在中国，三文鱼是中国**很受**欢迎的寿司种类，甚至有不少中国人到日本的回转寿司店只点三文鱼。

However, I don't understand how 受 works in the first article. If it is a verb and the whole sentence is a modifier to "寿司种类", then there should be a subject to a verb "很受".

At least on the second article, I understand that 中国 is a subject and 很受 is a verb, both of them modify 寿司种类 via 的. But on the first article, there is no subject on the "很受中国人欢迎的"... It might not be a verb to begin with, since if I remove 很受, it still seems to make sense (in this case 中国人 is a subject and 欢迎 is a verb...).

Comment: By the way, in the second sentence, 中国 is not the subject of （很）受. It should be short for 在中国, which is a prepositional phrase like in China in English. That's why I said in my answer. It repeat twice "在中国" in the second sentence. The second sentence is a bad example.

Comment: CCG calls this lexical passive, see comment #2 following answer #1 of
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/24396/objects-with-potential-complements/24399#24399 more examples lexical passive from CCG: using 得到、遭到，他得到朋友门的支持。她的行为遭到父母的批评。我的建议得到妹妹的支持。老师得到学生的尊敬。他遭到沉重的打击。来宾遭到主人的冷落。lexical passive generally disyllabic nominalised verb  formal object of a disyllabic 'receive' verb, which has a V+到 structure....alternative form .. disyllabic expressions V+N format..遭殃、罹难、受伤、得救、惹祸、遇险，孩子受了伤，人质遇难了，病人得救了

Answer (score 1):

The main parts of the sentence is 三文鱼(subject) 是(verb) 寿司种类(object).很受中国人欢迎的 and 中国很受欢迎的 are the modifier of 寿司种类.

To me, the first sentence is better, because in the second sentence it repeats 中国 twice. 在**中国**，三文鱼是**中国**很受欢迎的寿司种类. It could be better to remove the second 中国. 在中国，三文鱼是很受欢迎的寿司种类.

受 is short for 受到， meaning 'to get or getting'.

The phrase 很受中国人欢迎的 means 'getting warmly welcomed by Chinese people'.

As a whole, 三文鱼寿司是很受中国人欢迎的寿司种类 can be translated to Salmon sushi is the type which is warmly beloved/welcomed by Chinese people.

The subject for 受 is 寿司种类. In fact, it's a passive voice here. That 寿司种类
is 受到中国人欢迎. This is the same as "寿司种类**被**中国人欢迎". Somehow, 受到 here is the nice way to express “被” I think.

Comment: I understand the whole sentence structure but what I don't understand is the modifier part. Why on the first sentence does 很受 not have a subject?

Comment: Its subject is 寿司种类. 寿司种类 is modified by the phrase. It's like in English, "寿司种类, which is warmly welcomed by Chinese."

Comment: @Blaszard  the  subject in the first sentence is 三文鱼(寿司) which is a "寿司种类"

Comment: @TangHo Yes I know. 三文鱼寿司(S) - 是(V) - 寿司种类(C). But I don't understand the structure on the modifier part - 很受中国人欢迎.

Comment: @Blaszard does it become more clear if you insert 的 after 受? It was simply omitted in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Blaszard wrote: *I understand the whole sentence structure but what I don't understand is the modifier part. Why on the first sentence does 很受 not have a subject?*

Active voice sentence

> [中国人很欢迎三文鱼寿司]= [Chinese people very welcome salmon sushi ]
>
> [中国人 is the subject] [欢迎 is the verb] [三文鱼寿司 is the object]

~

~Passive voice sentence emphasizes the object

> [三文鱼寿司很受中国人欢迎]= [salmon sushi is very welcomed by Chinese people]
>
> [三文鱼寿司 is the object] [很受 is the passive voice marker that marks 三文鱼寿司 as the object] [中国人 is the subject] [欢迎 is the verb]

~

> "[受](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/423/)" *[4] preceding a verb to form a passive voice*

Comment: I think your answer is debatable. In 三文鱼寿司很受中国人欢迎, 欢迎 could be simply a noun word, 中国人 is a modifier for 欢迎. It's just like 中国人的欢迎. 三文鱼寿司 (subject) + 很（adv.）受（verb）+ 中国人（modifier）欢迎（object noun.）.I agree 受 conveys a passive voice, but it's different from the usage of 被. With 被, you have to add a verb to address passive. 受 itself as a verb connotes passive by nature, but its subject is often the target of the noun(欢迎 in this case) following it.In order to explain/interpret, sometimes we have to translate this kind of sentences into a passive voice in English, but indeed it works like an active

Answer (score 1):

> "在中国，三文鱼是中国很受欢迎的寿司种类"
>   
> I think it shuold be "在中国，三文鱼是很受欢迎的寿司种类".
>   
> 很受 do same work in two article.